# How widely are long-touch events supported?

Tags: android, long-press

I think that the **long-touch event** is supported on 99% of Android devices, but not sure about it.

Are there any exceptions? Like **vendor specific** or **Android version specific** exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by a "long-touch" event, as there really is nothing by that name in Android that I can think of.

If you mean a long-*click* event (e.g., `setOnLongClickListener()`), all Android devices that legitimately have the Android Market (a.k.a., Google Play) on them will support this, as they will not pass the compatibility test suite otherwise.

If you mean a *touch* event, not all Android devices have touchscreens, such as Google TV. Such devices can still generate a long-*click* event, using arrow keys or a D-pad or whatever controller the device supports.

Comment: Thanks sir, I meant `long click` such as used for `registerForContextMenu()` or `setOnLongClickListener()`, are those based on same event?

Comment: @MarekSebera: Yes, `registerForContextMenu()` uses a long-click event.